# How can I get a badge in a UIBarButtonItem?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uibarbuttonitem, badge

I want to set a badge number for a UIBarButtonItem in my UIToolbar.  Is this possible?  It will function the same was as the normal app icon's badge number.  Any advice?  I have a method that returns a number that is set as the badge count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Toolbar items don't usually display badge numbers, those are usually TabBars. That aside, if you use a custom view for the item in the toolbar you can create a view and add it on top of your item.

To make the badge stretch you can set it as the background image using the *resizableImage WithCapInsets:* or *stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:topCapHeight:* depending on your iOS target. The number is just a white text UILabel.

You can use this image:

[image: Badge image]